# Get public address of django application

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a django application, listening to 127.0.0.1, and reachable via nginx.

What are my options in order to get information about the public IP (the ones clients are using) from within the django application?

Currently I am doing:

```
def get_local_ip(request):
    """Return the local IP (where the application is listening to)"""
    # TODO: this should be the server IP as seen by the UI (the public IP, where nginx is listening)
    return request.META.get('HTTP_HOST') if request else None
```

But this returns `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your nginx configuration needs to add that to the headers, not sure that's done by default. The `$server_addr` is the one you need to add to the headers, so in your nginx config you would need to add (assuming you're using reverse proxy):

```
proxy_set_header X-Server-IP $server_addr;
```

And then in your `get_local_ip` method you'd be able to access that header with:

```
return request.META.get('HTTP_X_SERVER_IP')
```

Note that if your nginx server is behind a load balancer, this still won't be the address your users "see", since they see the IP address of your load balancer. The address they see is:

```
import socket
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(request.META.get('SERVER_NAME'))
```

which just resolves your domain name using DNS (and may slow down your request, since a DNS lookup needs to be made, depending on the TTL you have set in your DNS records)